# Why does this basic go-routine program return true?

Tags: go, channel

I'm new to Go and i'm trying to understand why this code returns:

```
12
true
```

Heres the simple program:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func foo(c chan int, myValue int) {
    c <- myValue * 2
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    go foo(c, 3)
    go foo(c, 6)

    v1, v2 := <-c

    fmt.Println(v1)
    fmt.Println(v2)
}
```

Is it true just because it gets some random value back?

Comment: You should take the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/). Specifically [this part](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/4).

Answer (score 4):

The second value in a two value [receive](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator) assigment is a boolean reporting whether the communication succeeded.  The value `v1` is the value received from the channel.  The value `v2` is true because communication succeeded.